# Bloggers are on top of their descriptions

Tags: bug, design, blog

On the blog on author pages like [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/acivitillo/), the image for the authors are on top of their descriptions:

> [image: image of bug]

I’m viewing this on my iPhone in Safari, but it’s probably more related to my phone being really small.

Comment: Happens on a desktop monitor as well, making the browser window smaller.  Unusably horribly smaller.  Time for a new phone, yay.

Comment: Sloppy. Should be fixed.

Comment: Same experience on Android version 7 running up-to-date Brave browser, as well as Google Chrome.